# How can I import a msf file from an old thunderbird version?

Tags: thunderbird, import-mail

I backed up my thunderbird inbox folder a long time ago. I didn't back up the full profile directory, just the IMAP folder which looks as follows:

```
ImapMail/IMAP.domain_name/INBOX
ImapMail/IMAP.domain_name/INBOX.msf
ImapMail/IMAP.domain_name/INBOX.sbd
ImapMail/IMAP.domain_name/INBOX.sbd/Drafts.msf
```

I have a brand new Thunderbird installation. NO accounts have been setup there. How can I read the mails in the INBOX directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't.  An msf file is just the index, which gets recreated if it is missing when you open the actual mbox.  In your case, you are using IMAP, so the mail is stored on the server.  Just configure thunderbird to connect to the server and it will find all your mail on the server.

If you were not using IMAP, then you would just set up thunderbird, close it, and copy the backed up files back into your profile directory.

Comment: I figured out that just pointing your local directory to be the correct folder just works.

Answer (score 4):

In your case it would be better to create a new Local Folder in order not to mess up with your working IMAP folder inside your account which is being synchronized with the IMAP server by default.

1) First check your Local Folders settings (right click "Local Folders" > "Settings", Account name: Local Folders, Local directory: CHECK THE PATH TO YOUR DESIRED DIRECTORY INSIDE YOUR PROFILE FOLDER)

2) Create new subfolder (you may later copy or move your messages to any folder you like, including a synchronized IMAP folder inside any account): Right click "Local Folders" > choose "New Folder..." > PROVIDE A NAME FOR THE NEW FOLDER

3) Go to the folder and copy your .msf files into it (there should be normally pairs of files with the same name like `Inbox.msf`, `Inbox`, `Sent.msf`, `Sent` etc.). One file is for storing messages and the other one is for the index.

4) Restart Tunderbird

5) New subfolders (`Inbox`, `Sent`, etc.) with your messages should appear inside your "Local Folder"

This is for Thunderbird v60.9.0 (64-bit) on Linux

Comment: I thought I backed up the content of the whole inbox so there should be a way to see it again. This worked. Thanks for the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Installed Thunderbird 31.0 on my new computer.  Found the old profile `xxxxxx.default` folder on my previous computer, selected all the files in there and copied them to the new `yyyyy.default` folder in my Windows 8.1 profile in `D:Users\Me\Appdata\Roaming`.  Then I said "Yes" to overwrite.  It all just worked.